# Sewer smell from floor drain

Tags: plumbing, drain, drainage

i have a small drain built into the ground, and once in a while at random times, it smells like sewers. The smell also stops after a random amount of time. It can go some days without smell, and the smell typically lingers for a couple of hours.

I have tried to rinse it and the "ball" (a standard feature to plug the drain automatically should it overflow due to heavy rains) i have tried running water everywhere in the home if a broken water lock (might not be the english word) should have evaporated.

I have tried putting a small amount of bacteria killer direcly into the drain.

I am out of ideas as to why, and how it can be fixed.

Comment: All drains are suppose to have P-traps(water locks) for each plumbing device.  Possible yours does not or it has a leak.  Most P-traps should last two or three weeks without being used/having water pour down/in them, before drying out/leaking sewer gas/smell.  Other P-traps should not affect each other.  Will need to remove ground/covering and check.

Comment: Are "random times" one day smelly, one day not smelly (then maybe it's a siphoning trap)?  Or is it more like a week or a month will pass before it changes (then maybe it's just drying up)?    Pour water down *this drain* (not other ones).   If smells still come out afterwards, it's probably siphoning.

Comment: I have had good luck adding some vegetable oil in floor drains to prevent evaporation with some oil on top of the water it doesn’t evaporate because of the high humidity in the drain and the water trapped under the oil. Water can flow and if not two much the oil stays in place but if a high flow sometimes you have to add. Give it a try it also works on toilets for “snow birds” keeps them from drying out and the house stinking or blowing up that has happened in the past.